# skipping input in do-while using scanner JAVA

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, do-while

I am using a do-while loop that loops based on the input of the user as a 'Y' or 'N'. If the user chooses to continue by pressing 'Y' or 1 (for simplicity), on the second iteration it skips the first input in the same loop.

```
do{
       System.out.println("Enter the location: ");
       cartItem.purchaseLocation = input.nextLine();  // This input is skipped on second iteration

       System.out.println("Enter the product description: ");
       cartItem.productDescription = input.nextLine();

       System.out.println("Enter the price of the item: ");
       cartItem.productPrice = input.nextDouble();

       System.out.println("Enter the quantity: ");
       cartItem.quantity = input.nextInt();


       cartList.add(cartItem);

       System.out.println("Do you want to add more items ? y = 1 / n = 0: ");
       exitVar = input.nextInt();

   }while(exitVar!=0);            // Repeat till no more items need to be added in the cart
```

So when the user presses input 0 to repeat the procedure, the line

> cartItem.purchaseLocation = input.nextLine();

which is the very first input in the loop will be skipped. Any suggestions what might be wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

same question as [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

input.nextInt() does not read a line, when your input is "1\n", it read "1" and leaves "\n" to the next read, which is

```
cartItem.purchaseLocation = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `input.nextLine()` use `input.next()` assuming `input` is a `Scanner` object.

If it is not, please clarify what `input` is.

Comment: Your solution cannot solve the issue but lead to more other issues later.